# ajax call inside anchor tag in mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement ajax call inside  Grid column using anchor tag and passing Id of employee to ajax funtion. But its not working. Where I have done mistake

```
 grid1.Column("", header: "Edit", format: @<text><a href="@Url.Action("", "", new { id = @item.empId })" onclick="editEmp()" class="openDialog">Edit</a></text>)
```

Below is Ajax funtion-

```
function editEmp(empId) {
            $.get("@Url.Action("EditEmployee", "BootStrap")",
                     {
                         empId: empId

                     }, function (data) {
                         alert('hi');
  });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
grid1.Column("", header: "Edit", format: @<text><a href="@Url.Action("", "", new { id = @item.empId })" onclick="editEmp(@item.empId)" class="openDialog">Edit</a></text>)


function editEmp(empId) {
    $.get('@Url.Action("EditEmployee", "BootStrap")', { empId: empId })
        .done(function () {
            console.log("success");
        })
.fail(function () {
    console.log("error");
})
};
```

Comment: I think there is no problem with ajax , something is wrong in grid column and anchor tag. on clicking it navigate to home page

Comment: still same result with your suggestion wasif-shahjahan